# RegExp: Split text by delimiter

Tags: python, regex

In Python, what's the best way to split a text like the following so that I can have 3 lists that represent each package (system, network and another_package)?

```
package system

config system 'system'
    option hostname 'test-system'

package network

config interface 'lan'
    option ifname 'eth0'
    option proto 'none'

package another_package

config etc 'etc'
    option name 'val'
```

Eg (very ugly):

```
re.split('package ', text)
```

Would it be possible to capture the package name too?

**EDIT** - maybe I figured it out:

```
re.split('(package\s\w*)', text)
```

Comment: Are you in control of the file structure? Why not use YAML or something that is already established?

Comment: No, I'm parsing the configuration format of OpenWRT and LEDE

Answer (score 2):

Your "very ugly" `re.split` already does it as far as I can tell.   One possible tweak would be to make the pattern `r'^\s*package '` and add the multi-line flag `re.M`.  That would ensure that it only matches "package" as the first word on a line.

This captures all the non-blank sections:

```
[section.strip() for section in re.split('^\s*package ', text, flags=re.M) if section.strip()]
```

...and the first word in each section is the package name.